# Django Rest Framework get method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have some problems with Django rest framework. I don't know basics but it's a small piece of code that I need to do. So I have api.py that looks like:

```py
from rest_framework import generics, permissions
from rest_framework.response import Response
from knox.models import AuthToken
from .thisisfile import Thisisfile


class ScraperAPI(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny,
    ]

    def get(self, request):
        return Response({
            "name": Thisisfile(),
            "result": True,
        })
```

What I need to do here is, to get value (name for example) that I'm defining in the get request.
So this name must be passed from this API file to Thisisfile(). And to get a response like.

```py
{
    "user": {
        "name": "here is the name"
     },
    "result": true
}
```

This is how Thisisfile looks like

```py
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import serializers
import json


class Thisisfile(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def getsomething(name):
        return Response({
            "name": name,
        })

    getsomething()
```

So to finalize the question. How to grab this name in Thisisfile and return it as a json? I know this is a stupid code for someone who knows Python but I'm not really good at it.

Comment: "I don't know basics" this isn't a helpdesk. It kinda is your responsibility to try and understand, not just throw the problem to us

Comment: I know, I want to understand what I have to do for future ofc, but if I don't know basics how could I? :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the viewsets documentation - I think it can do what you intend to achieve.
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong to my knowledge. In Class thisisfile where the name come from.? Is it declared in any model?.

Check about  serializerMethodField. That's might help you out.